# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_18_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I'm testing out tf.keras with tf.data, so I can do minibatch optimization. I'm using the MNIST dataset, and I'm running the code in Google Colab. However, when I try to train the network, I always get this error:
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_18_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,)`. Here is my code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

!git clone https://github.com/DanorRon/my_repo
%cd my_repo
!ls

batch_size = 100
epochs = 10
alpha = 0.01
lambda_ = 0.01
h1 = 50

train = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/my_repo/mnist_train.csv.zip')
test = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/my_repo/mnist_test.csv.zip')

x_train = train.loc[:, '1x1':'28x28']
y_train = train.loc[:, 'label']

x_test = test.loc[:, '1x1':'28x28']
y_test = test.loc[:, 'label']

Train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
Train.batch(batch_size).repeat(10).shuffle(1000)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(784, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(h1, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha),
             loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(Train, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=600)
```

I don't know what the problem is. I think my dimensions are correct, and I can't see any other problem. How do I fix this problem?

Edit: I’ve looked more/tested things to find the answer, but I can’t find anything that works. I have no idea at all what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe you should split `x_train` and `y_train` from `Train`, and rewrite `model.fit` as `model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=600)`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the problem without splitting the dataset?

Comment: Also, how do I break the dataset apart? I can’t find anything on the docs.

Comment: ```from keras.datasets import mnist
 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()```
Sorry, I haven't used the dataset in csv form. Generally, I use the api of keras. It has the same api with ```tensorflow.keras```.